# Bluetooth times out on headset, need audio ping

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am a total newbie and I'm really only able to create programming by seeing what someone else wrote and then try to change it to make it work for me.

The problem. I have a simple android program running on a Fire table that plays a 5 min audio file connected to a bluetooth headset. The headset has an issue that if it does not get signal for more than 5 minutes, it turns off the bluetooth connection. This is in the headset and cannot be changed.

I need to a way to have my program keep sending an audio signal (something as easy as a beep) at least every 5 minutes BUT not while the actual 5 min audio file is playing.

Anyone have any suggestions?  Below is my super simple code:

```
package com.example.myapplication5;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    public void playn(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create( this, R.raw.nature);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   stopPlayer();
                }
            });
        }
        player.start();
      }

      public void playd(View v) {
          if (player == null) {
              player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.space);
              player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     stopPlayer();
                 }
             });
         }
         player.start();
     }

     public void playu(View v) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ultra);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stopPlayer();
                }
            });
        }
        player.start();
    }

    public void pause(View v) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
        }
    }

    public void stop(View v) {
        stopPlayer();
    }

    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (player !=null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "MediaPlayer released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       stopPlayer();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please pin point code which is suspect. It is too much to read

Comment: nothing us suspect. I need someone to help me add code that will send an audio ping or play an audio file once every 5 minutes  if the main audio file is not playing. Please read my request. I thought I outlined my need